# Why do I get an error when I try to begin an equation?

Tags: equations

This is what I have typed so far in latex:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letter]{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1.5in, top=0.5in]{geometry}


\onehalfspacing



\begin{document}



\title{Homework Chapter 5}

\author{}




\maketitle 



\section*{Section 5.2: 4,5,7}

\paragraph{4.}
Let $\alpha$ be a complex number. Show that if $(1+z)^{\alpha}$ is taken as $e^{\alpha \operatorname{Log}(1+z)}$, then for $|z|< 1$\\

$(1+z)^{\alpha} = 1 + \displaystyle\frac{\alpha}{1}z + \frac{\alpha(\alpha -1)}{1\cdot2}z^{2} + \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)}{1\cdot2\cdot3}z^{3} + \cdots$\\

In general, 

\begin{equation}

\displaystyle\frac{d^{j}}{dz^{j}}(1+z)^{\alpha}=\frac{\alpha !(1+z)^{\alpha - j}}{(\alpha - j)!}

\end{equation}
```

I get an error with the following code:

```
\begin{equation}

\displaystyle\frac{d^{j}}{dz^{j}}(1+z)^{\alpha}=\frac{\alpha !(1+z)^{\alpha - j}}{(\alpha - j)!}

\end{equation}
```

I was wondering if someone could clarify why this happens?

Comment: You can't have a blank line inside an equation environment.

Comment: One of the reason you leave blank lines is (probably in your mind) to make your code more readable. But no, you cannot have blank lines within any type of math mode. If you must keep this coding habit, then you could type a `%` at the beginning of each of your blank lines (in equations).

Comment: A separate observation: In an `equation` environment, TeX is in display-style math mode automatically -- no need for the `\displaystyle` directive.

Comment: Also, `letter` is not an option recognized the `article` document class. You should try `letterpaper` instead.

Answer (score 5):

The error is caused by the blank lines inside the `equation` environment: no blank line should appear there.

There are also several “non fatal” errors in your code.

1. Never end paragraphs in text with `\\`, but with a blank line.
2. Use `\displaystyle` very sparingly: I believe to have used it in the body of a document just a handful of times. For the special occasion where you need a “big fraction” in text mode, there is `\dfrac`. In the first case you use it, it is rather `equation*` than an inline equation.
3. Using `\operatorname{Log}` is fine, but I guess that using `\Log` after defining `\DeclareMathOperator{\Log}{Log}` is better, because in a complex analysis context the symbol will be quite often used.
4. As a subtlety, remember to add `\,` after `!` if something immediately follows a factorial.
5. `\cdots` and `\ldots` are fine, but just `\dots` is in general better. However, when `\dots` is not between alike symbols, you need to help `amsmath`; in your case, use `\dotsb`.

I also reorganized a bit your preamble.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1.5in, top=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}

\onehalfspacing

\DeclareMathOperator{\Log}{Log}

\begin{document}

\title{Homework Chapter 5}
\author{}

\maketitle 

\section*{Section 5.2: 4,5,7}

\paragraph{4.}
Let $\alpha$ be a complex number. Show that if $(1+z)^{\alpha}$ is taken 
as $e^{\alpha \Log(1+z)}$, then for $|z|< 1$
\begin{equation*}
(1+z)^{\alpha} = 1 + \frac{\alpha}{1}z + 
\frac{\alpha(\alpha -1)}{1\cdot2}z^{2} +
\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)}{1\cdot2\cdot3}z^{3} + \dotsb
\end{equation*}
In general, 
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^{j}}{dz^{j}}(1+z)^{\alpha}=
\frac{\alpha! \, (1+z)^{\alpha - j}}{(\alpha - j)!}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you see that the input is simpler? You don't have to worry where line ends: it's TeX that generally takes care of that.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to getting into the habit of *not* creating blank lines inside display-math environments (such as `equation`), do also try to get used to not treating LaTeX like it's some kludgy version of MS Word, i.e., like it's a word processor. What do I mean by that? Basically, get over your instincts of applying lots and lots of visual formatting. Instead, get used to writing what you *mean* -- and let LaTeX handle the nitty-gritty formatting issues.

It takes a couple of minutes (ok, a couple of hours...) to get used to not treating LaTeX like it's a word processor. But once you get the hang of it, you'll really start to enjoy LaTeX much more. Here's how I would re-write your code to make it more "LaTeX-y":

[image]

Note, for instance, the use of `\[` and `\]` to start and end an unnumbered display-math environment. Learning not to use `\\` to force line breaks (other than in `tabular` and `array` environments) is particularly important. And don't leave blank lines (which tell TeX to start a new paragraph) immediately before `\[` or `\begin{equation}`. The `amsmath` package also provides the instruction `\DeclareMathOperator`, which is handy for creating new "operators" such as `\Log`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article} % not 'letter' 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Log}{Log}
\usepackage{enumitem} % allows fine-tuning of 'enumerate' environment
\begin{document}

\title{Homework Chapter 5}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle

\setcounter{section}{5}  % just for this example
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\subsection{Problems 4, 5, and 7}

\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, label=\bfseries\arabic*., start=4]

\item Let $\alpha$ be a complex number. Show that if $(1+z)^{\alpha}$ is
taken as $e^{\alpha\Log(1+z)}$, then for $|z|< 1$,
\[
(1+z)^{\alpha} = 1 + \frac{\alpha}{1} z + \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{1\cdot2} z^{2}
   + \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)}{1\cdot2\cdot3} z^{3} + \dotsb
\]
In general,
\begin{equation} \label{eq:taylor_exp}
\frac{d^{j}}{dz^{j}} (1+z)^{\alpha}
  =\frac{\alpha! (1+z)^{\alpha - j}}{(\alpha - j)!}
\end{equation}
\dots

\item \dots

\stepcounter{enumi}

\item \dots

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\operatorname{Log}` is common in complex analysis, to denote the “principal branch” of the logarithm. Please, never suggest to change “log” to “ln”: everybody is entitled their preferences.

Comment: I was wondering why we put `\label{eq:taylor_exp}` after `\begin{equation}`?

Comment: @K.M - The code that's executed when `\begin{equation}` is encountered (pun intended) steps the counter called `equation`. The `\label` statement must come after the code that increments the associated counter.